# Space Complexity for linked list

Tags: java, space-complexity

My question is that if we create multiple reference variables to an object in java or python, does the space complexity increases or it is same?

for example I have a linked list  of input size n which is head
if i create another reference variable duplicate and point it to head like

```
public LinkedList duplicate(LinkedList head)
{    
LinkedList duplicate=head;
return duplicate;
}
```

what is the additional space complexity is it O(1) or O(n) in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The space complexity remains linear or O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's O(n). New objects are created in heap space, and the references to these objects are stored in stack memory.

Comment: why not O(1) as the heap size is same for all reference variables? we are just pointing a new variable to it. does that mean if i create 2 other reference variables it will be O(2n).

Comment: O(1) seems to make more sense to me since we're not creating a new LinkedList buffer

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be `O(1)` space complexity. We generally don't factor in the size of input parameters in space complexity because there's really nothing you can do to improve or eliminate them. We only care if we're creating an additional buffer in our algorithm. Consider the same with arrays.

1. No additional buffer. Space Complexity: O(1)

```
public int[] noBufferMethod(int[] data) {
    int[] justReference = data; // Points to input so no extra space
    return justReference;
}
```

2. With additional buffer. Space Complexity: O(n)

```
public int[] withBufferMethod(int[] data) {
    int[] buffer = new int[data.length]; // Creates additional buffer
    return buffer;
}
```

The exact same applies to a LinkedList (or any collection).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for additional space Complexity, right ?

Additional Space Complexity remains constant in your case, just creating a reference variable and making it point to the head, doesn't create the whole linked list again, it is simply another variable pointing to head node and it is not creating any extra nodes. Any new node is created using the `new` Keyword in java.

total space complexity remains O(n) as it is space taken by your Linkedlist.